# Run a function as a separate node.js process?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, concurrency, parallel-processing

Is it possible to run a function as a completely separate node.js process? For example:

```
var parallel = require("parallel");
parallel(function(){
    var app = require("express")();
    app.on("/",function(req,res){ res.send("hi"); });
    app.listen(80);
},function callback(err,stdout){
    console.log("process terminated!")
});
```

Is something like that possible?

Comment: Related: [node.js on multi-core machines](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2387724/538551)

Comment: Good link, but possibly outdated?

Comment: The [highest up-voted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8685968/538551) is up-to-date.

Comment: Oh wow, why that answer is buried?

Comment: From [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107096/how-are-answers-sorted) (see second comment)

Comment: Damn do you have a link for everything I say :(

Answer (score 2):

First off, try to use the idiomatic way of load-balancing. For node, this is asynchronous design. See these other answers for more info:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8685968/538551
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11278689/538551

There are options though:

- threading: [threads_a_go_go](https://npmjs.org/package/threads_a_gogo) ([source on github](https://github.com/xk/node-threads-a-gogo)).
- fibers: [node-fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers)

  - note, this only does concurrency, not parallism; it's more for code structure than parallel processing ([more here](http://bjouhier.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/fibers-and-threads-in-node-js-what-for/))
- [apache thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) [nodejs plugin](http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/nodejs/): not directly what you're asking for, but this is the route I'd go. I'd implement the hard stuff in something low-level (like C)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [node.js on multi-core machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387724/node-js-on-multi-core-machines) and [Dave Dopson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8685968/1479606)

Basically you can run multiple processes and let them communicate with each other.