# Does node.js use threads/thread pool internally?

Tags: multithreading, node.js

I've decided to familiarize myself with node.js and have read a several articles on the subject. What remained unclear to me is if node.js creates new threads and/or schedules tasks on threads from a thread pool when you call  node.js functions.

For example if I call `fs.readFile` is it executed on a different thread?

If yes, [how] can I write my own function `readFileCustomized` or `doLongOperation` to run on a different thread?

Comment: Worth reading this: [Which would be better for concurrent tasks on node.js? Fibers? Web-workers? or Threads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773564/which-would-be-better-for-concurrent-tasks-on-node-js-fibers-web-workers-or-t)

Comment: @jfriend00 haven't seen this one and it's definitely useful. Thank you for suggesting it.

Comment: Just tried to find the source for everything that's `fs.readFile` related: `fs.readFile > fs.read > ASYNC_CALL(read(2)) (macro) > FSReqWrap > ReqWrap > BaseObject`. If you want to check the intrinsics of `fs.readFile` it will take a little while.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no async API for file operations so node.js uses a thread pool for that. You can see it in the code of [libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv).

[The pool can run 4 threads](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/v0.10.19/src/unix/threadpool.c#L32):

```
static uv_thread_t default_threads[4];
```

Blocking FS tasks are posted with [uv__work_submit](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/v0.10.19/src/unix/threadpool.c#L159). For example, here's how [read is implemented](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/v0.10.19/src/unix/fs.c#L736):

```
int uv_fs_read(uv_loop_t* loop, uv_fs_t* req,
               uv_file file,
               void* buf,
               size_t len,
               int64_t off,
               uv_fs_cb cb) {
  INIT(READ);
  req->file = file;
  req->buf = buf;
  req->len = len;
  req->off = off;
  POST;
}

...

#define POST                                                                  \
  do {                                                                        \
    if ((cb) != NULL) {                                                       \
      uv__work_submit((loop), &(req)->work_req, uv__fs_work, uv__fs_done);    \
      return 0;                                                               \
    }                                                                         \
    else {                                                                    \
      uv__fs_work(&(req)->work_req);                                          \
      uv__fs_done(&(req)->work_req, 0);                                       \
      return (req)->result;                                                   \
    }                                                                         \
  }                                                                           \
  while (0)
```

If you want to implement your own threads, you can check this [great introduction](http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/threads.html).

Comment: I don't think any thread is blocked for the duration of the IO though.

Comment: libuv ultimately uses stdio's read: https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/v0.10.19/src/unix/fs.c#L184 which is blocking.

Comment: Thank you for this, I've already studied the last linked article, but it concerns libuv, I was wondering how much of that is exposed in node.js. It does not look like thread pool/threading is exposed at all.

Comment: I'm unqualified to read the C code. I wonder whether this code path is ever invoked. That would be very much against the purpose of libuv. Surprising to say the least. Care to look at how socket IO is done?

Comment: You check check [node-lame's](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-lame/blob/master/src/node_mpg123.cc) code. It uses threads and libuv.

Comment: all network IO is fully async (it uses epoll for Linux for example). However, FS is always blocking in a thread pool.

Comment: Ah yes, the example with node-lame makes sense. Although it's binding to some native code it showcases where threading would be most useful. I suspected that if you wanted to do threading you would have to write in in C/C++. It seems to be the case indeed.