# node.js – internally spawning userland process threads?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, concurrency, htop

I have noticed that when spawning a very simple node process, `htop` will show multiple (what I learned today is called) [userland process threads](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10362/why-does-htop-show-more-process-than-ps).

```sh
echo "setInterval(() => console.log(' '), 1000);" > test.js
node test.js
# while node is running, somewhere else:
htop
```

[image]

What I see now in htop, filtering by the script name:

- the main process (indicated in white color, with little but increasing CPU time)
- some (~5 or 6, depending on the machine?!) green lines, indicating userland process threads. Some of them seem to gather a tiny bit of CPU time.
- **Oddly enough**, this only happens on my linux machines (tested on two, bionic and xenial ubuntu). On MacOS, it only shows a single process. *This might be related to mismatching htop versions though …*

Most search results around node and threads talk about [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/dist./v12.12.0/docs/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_worker_threads), but I don't assume they're involved here. The behavior is similar even on node v8, where there was no such thing (and also, I'm not creating them, or even importing the `worker_threads` module).

Answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346097/does-node-js-use-threads-thread-pool-internally/20346545#20346545) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404784/how-nodejss-internal-threadpool-works-exactly) talk about an *internal thread pool*. But the numbers don't match (supposedly, there should be only 4 extra threads), and not seeing them on MacOS also doesn't make sense to me, and node creating them in the first place when there is no I/O whatsoever seems weird as well.

**My questions**:

- Am I right in assuming that those threads have nothing to do with worker threads?
- What is the purpose of those threads? Do they indeed belong to the *internal thread pool*?
- If they do, why do I get more than 4 (without `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE` being set)? And none on MacOS?

Versions:

- Ubuntu 16 and 18 LTS
- MacOS 11.2, both m1 and intel chips
- Node 8 and 14 (tested both versions on all OSes, results stay the same)
- htop 2.1 (on linux) and 3.0 (on MacOS)