# Using Web-Workers in stand alone V8 Javascript Engine

Tags: javascript, html, v8, web-worker

I tried to adopt the shell.cc sample from the V8 distribution package for my own purposes.

I want to spawn a web-worker to execute a long-running script, and execute:

```
var myWorker = new Worker("my_task.js");
```

But I receive the following error message:

```
(shell):1: ReferenceError: Worker is not defined
var myWorker = new Worker("my_task.js");
                   ^
ReferenceError: Worker is not defined
    at (shell):1:20
```

Is there a way to activate Web Workers in the V8 Engine?

Thank you in advance for any help on this issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'd use the [Child Process library for node](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) or one of the other libraries that implements threading.  As far as I know, web workers are a browser thing, not part of the standard node.js implementation and if you want that sort of API, you would need to use a third party library that implements something like that API.

Other useful references:

[Lightweight Web Worker API implementation with native threads](https://www.npmjs.org/package/webworker-threads)

[Concurrency on Node Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773564/which-would-be-better-for-concurrent-tasks-on-node-js-fibers-web-workers-or-t)

[Web Worker implementation in node](https://github.com/pgriess/node-webworker)

Answer (score 2):

Too late though: But for any one still searching for it:

Check d8.cc file in v8 source code , it exposes Worker Template:
[image]

Comment: How to use these templates?