# Spawn a new independent process in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, multiple-processes

Is there any way to spawn a new independent process from the current running script?

I am trying to run a new script from an already running script. The new script should be independent of the one that called it.

Comment: In what context? The browser? Node.js? Something else?

Comment: _"The new script should be independent of the one that called it."_ What do you mean by "independent"? Can you include `javascript` that you have tried at Question?

Comment: by indepenedent i mean that it should keep running even if the original process stops

Comment: take a look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773564/which-would-be-better-for-concurrent-tasks-on-node-js-fibers-web-workers-or-t

Answer (score 9):

You can use the 'detached' option and the unref() method to make child process independent.

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const child = spawn(process.argv[0], ['child_program.js'], {
  detached: true,
  stdio: ['ignore']
});

child.unref();
```

Ref: [Node.js document](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer to this question is to use `detached: true` and call `unref()` on the spawned process. This is also what the documentation states.
However, using *Node 10*, I can't get the sub process (a shell script that restarts my Node process after other commands) to survive the Node process: it is always killed when the parent Node process is stopped, no matter how I do it (I also tried calling `disconnect()`, but it does not work since there is no active IPC channel). I believe this is a bug in this version of Node (there's [this official issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/36808) but for Windows).

My workaround is to use the `at` command. Perhaps there's an equivalent for Windows, but this will work only for Linux.
So, instead of calling directly your shell script, you call the script by piping it to `at` with a given execution date (if you just put "now" it will be executed right away)

```bash
echo /usr/sbin/my-script.sh arg1 | sudo at now
```