# create timer with react native using es6

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, reactjs, react-native

I am looking to add a timer to my app which is built using react native.

I have looked at the link to the [timer mixin](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers.html#content) in the documentation however I have built the rest of the app using es6 so this won't be compatible.

I have tried the below.

In my Main class I have a function called `getTimerCountDown`

```
getTimerCountDown() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setTimeRemaining(this.getTimeRem()-1);
    }, 1000);
}

getTimeRem() {
    return this.state.timeRemaining;
}
```

I have tried calling this in `componentDidUpdate` as shown below. This works as I want it to if I don't make any other interactions with the UI.

If I do (eg I have a button I can click on the view.) as `componentDidUpdate gets called again the conunter gets really quick (as it is getting called x number of times)

```
componentDidUpdate(){
    this.getTimerCountDown();
}
```

I am not sure if I am completly on the wrong track here or a small change to what I have done can get me what I want.
What is the best way to get a countdown timer working in react native using es6?

Timer Class 
on main page

```
<Timer timeRem={this.getTimeRem()} />
```

returns

```
render(){
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text> This is the Timer : {this.props.setTimer}  - {this.props.timeRem} </Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: try to change your getTimerCountdown and make it return `setState()`

Comment: What part of the `TimerMixin` isn't compatible? The docs for it even use an es6 example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not really sure how that would work even without any other UI interactions. `componentDidUpdate` is called every time the component is re-rendered, something that happens when the internal state or passed down props have changed. Not something you can count on to happen exactly every second.

How about moving the `getTimerCountDown` to your `componentDidMount` method (which is only called once), and then using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` to make sure the counter is decremented continuously?

Comment: This suggestion worked thanks.  how would you clearInterval in the context I have set up the getTimerCountDown function? I am not sure how I would do this as it assigned to a var like it commonly is?

Comment: You'd store the reference of the timer in either the component's state or a member variable of the component (not 100% if the latter's considered bad practice - if you don't need that reference to render the component at least). Then whenever you need to stop the timer you can pass that reference in `clearInterval` as usual. Does that answer your question?

Comment: This works if you want a simple countdown, but it is *not* temporally accurate because of the way `setInterval` and `setTimeout` drift. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29972322/146612

Answer (score 4):

Kinda late, but you can try out this component I made for dealing with timers and es6 components in react-native:

https://github.com/fractaltech/react-native-timer

Idea is simple, maintaining and clearing timer variables on the components is a pain, so simply, maintain them in a separate module. Example:

```
// not using ES6 modules as babel has broken interop with commonjs for defaults 
const timer = require('react-native-timer');

// timers maintained in the Map timer.timeouts 
timer.setTimeout(name, fn, interval);
timer.clearTimeout(name);

// timers maintained in the Map timer.intervals 
timer.setInterval(name, fn, interval);
timer.clearInterval(name);

// timers maintained in the Map timer.immediates 
timer.setImmediate(name, fn);
timer.clearImmediate(name);

// timers maintained in the Map timer.animationFrames 
timer.requestAnimationFrame(name, fn);
timer.cancelAnimationFrame(name);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

### Timer.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View,Text,Button,StyleSheet } from "react-native";
const timer = () => {};
class Timer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      remainingTime: 10
     };
    }

 countdownTimer(){
   this.setState({remainingTime:10 });
   clearInterval(timer);
   timer = setInterval(() =>{
        if(!this.state.remainingTime){
          clearInterval(timer);
          return false;
        }
        this.setState(prevState =>{
        return {remainingTime: prevState.remainingTime - 1}});
        },1000);
    }

    render() {
      return (
       <View style={styles.container}>
         <Text>Remaining time :{this.state.remainingTime}</Text>
          <Button title ="Start timer" onPress={()=>this.countdownTimer()}/>
       </View>
     );
   }
  }


  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
     flex:1,
     justifyContent:'center',
     alignItems:'center',
   } 
});

  export default Timer;
```

### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
  import { View,Text,Button,StyleSheet } from "react-native";
  import Timer from './timer';

  export default class App extends Component{
   render(
    return (<Timer />)
   );
 }
```

Comment: Good Work!Worked Great!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is full code how you can create a timer (pomodoro Timer) in react-native;

**Timer.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {Vibration, View, Button, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'


let pomInterval;

export default class Timer extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            minutes: 5,
            seconds: 0,
            workmins: 5,
            worksecs: 0,
            breakMins: 2,
            breakSecs: 0,
            timerState: 'WORK TIMER',
            btnState: 'Start'
        }
    }

    vibrate = () => {
        Vibration.vibrate([500, 500, 500])
    }

    pomTimer = () => {
        pomInterval = setInterval(() => {
            let newSec = this.state.seconds;
            newSec--;
            if(newSec < 0) {
                newSec = 59;
                this.state.minutes--;
            }
            this.setState({
                seconds: newSec,
            })

            if(newSec <= 0 && this.state.minutes <= 0) {
                this.vibrate();
                if(this.state.timerState == 'WORK TIMER') {
                    this.setState({
                        timerState: 'BREAK TIMER',
                        minutes: this.state.breakMins,
                        seconds: this.state.breakSecs
                        
                    })
                }else {
                    this.setState({
                        timerState: 'WORK TIMER',
                        minutes: this.state.workmins,
                        seconds: this.state.worksecs
                    })
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
    }


    changeWorkMin = mins => {
        clearInterval(pomInterval);
        this.setState({
            minutes: mins || 0,
            workmins: mins || 0,
            btnState: 'Start'
        })
    }

    changeWorkSec = secs => {
        clearInterval(pomInterval);
        this.setState({
            seconds: secs || 0,
            worksecs: secs || 0,
            btnState: 'Start'
        })
    }

    changeBreakMin = mins => {
        clearInterval(pomInterval);
        this.setState({
            breakMins: mins || 0,
            btnState: 'Start'
        })
    }

    changeBreakSec = secs => {
        clearInterval(pomInterval);
        this.setState({
            breakSecs: secs || 0,
            btnState: 'Start'
        })
    }

    // Creating the functionality for the pause/start button
    chnageBtnState = () => {
        if(this.state.btnState == 'Start') {
            this.pomTimer();
            this.setState({
                btnState: 'Pause'
            })

        }else {
            clearInterval(pomInterval);
            this.setState({
                btnState: 'Start'
            })
        }
    }

    // Creating the functionality for the reset button
    reset = () => {
        clearInterval(pomInterval);
        if(this.state.timerState == 'WORK TIMER') {
            this.setState({
                minutes: this.state.workmins,
                seconds: this.state.worksecs,
                btnState: 'Start'
            })
        }else {
            this.setState({
                minutes: this.state.breakMins,
                seconds: this.state.breakSecs,
                btnState: 'Start'
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.viewStyles}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyles}>{this.state.timerState}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.textStyles}>{this.state.minutes}:{this.state.seconds}</Text>
                <Text>
                    <Button title={this.state.btnState} onPress={this.chnageBtnState} />
                    <Button title='Reset' onPress={this.reset} />
                </Text>
                <Text>Work Time:</Text>
                <TextInput style={styles.inputStyles} value={this.state.workmins.toString()} placeholder='Work Minutes' onChangeText={this.changeWorkMin} keyboardType='numeric' />
                <TextInput style={styles.inputStyles} value={this.state.worksecs.toString()} placeholder='Work Seconds' onChangeText={this.changeWorkSec} keyboardType='numeric' />
                <Text>Break Time:</Text>
                <TextInput style={styles.inputStyles} value={this.state.breakMins.toString()} placeholder='Break Minutes' onChangeText={this.changeBreakMin} keyboardType='numeric' />
                <TextInput style={styles.inputStyles} value={this.state.breakSecs.toString()} placeholder='Break Seconds' onChangeText={this.changeBreakSec} keyboardType='numeric' />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

// Creating a style sheet to write some styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    viewStyles: {
        alignItems: 'center'
    },

    textStyles: {
        fontSize: 48
    },

    inputStyles: {
        paddingHorizontal: 50,
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 1
    }
})
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Timer from './timer';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Timer />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

This is how we can create a pomodoro timer, a timer which has both WORK TIMER and BREAK TIMER and it vibrates the phone as one of the timer reaches its end. I also added the input functionality i.e, you can dynamically change the value of the minutes and seconds (whether work timer or break timer is going on). I also added a start/pause button and a reset button.