# Get timer starts from 0 after click in memory game

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

It's my first question here. I was looking for a similar topic but I didn't find the answer that I could use. I would like to get a timer in my memory game that displays current time (I want to use Date object). I used a function from here [How to create an accurate timer in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971898/how-to-create-an-accurate-timer-in-javascript) but after the first click on the card, the time does not begin from 0. It shows the time that has elapsed since the page loading.

```
//variable for timer
var gameScore = $(".score-game");
var timer = $("#timer");
gameScore.html("0 seconds");
var hasGameStarted = false;
var score = Date.now();

    //timer function
    function countdownTimer() {
        if (hasGameStarted !== true) {
            scoreTimeout = setInterval(function() {
                var delta = Date.now() - score;
                gameScore.html(Math.floor(delta / 1000) + " seconds");
            }, 1000);
            hasGameStarted = true;
        }
    }
cards.on('click', function() {
countdownTimer();
});
```

If you want to see how works my game, check this site (timer is working good now but does not display time from date object):

https://borkson.github.io/Cars-Memory-Game/

Sorry for my English :(

Answer (score 0):

I understand your code, you mean that you start a timer calculated by delta variable and updated every 1000 milliseconds

```js
//variable for timer
var gameScore = $(".score-game");
var timer = $("#timer");
gameScore.html("0 seconds");
var hasGameStarted = false;
var score = Date.now();

//timer function
function countdownTimer() {
  if (hasGameStarted !== true) {
    scoreTimeout = setInterval(function() {
      var delta = Date.now() - score;
      gameScore.html(Math.floor(delta / 1000) + " seconds");
    }, 1000);
    hasGameStarted = true;
  }
}

$("#cards").on('click', function() {
  countdownTimer();
});
```

```css
#cards {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #73AD21;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="cards"></img>
<div class="score-game">score</div>
<div id="timer">timer</div>
```

Comment: Without an explanation this code and answer is meaningless

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a more-clever way, but you could...

var startTime = Date.now();

...then below, in your function...

var delta = startTime - score;

Does that help?

Comment: id didn't work because i had variable for Date.now() before (var score). Now it is looks like: 
    var score = Date.now();
    var startTime = Date.now();
    function countdownTimer() {
  if (hasGameStarted !== true) {
    scoreTimeout = setInterval(function() {
      var delta =startTime - score;
      gameScore.html(Math.floor(delta / 1000) + " seconds");
    }, 1000);
    hasGameStarted = true;
  }
}

Comment: try to use the js snippet tool it's a nice feature and helps to read code