# Javascript not able to make common functions for a prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I am trying to make timer in javascript using a prototype. Each time a new timer is created, a object of prototype is created. There are methods to increase time and print each second. The whole code snippet is as follows:

```js
function Timer(elem) {

  this.interval = null;
  this.currentTime = {
    sec: 0,
    min: 0,
    hr: 0
  };
  this.elem = elem;
};

Timer.prototype.start = function() {
  var self = this;
  if (!self.interval) {
    self.interval = setInterval(update, 1000);
  }

  function update() {
    incrementTime();
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    self.elem.innerText = getPrintableTime();
  }

  function incrementTime() {
    self.currentTime["min"] += Math.floor((++self.currentTime["sec"]) / 60);
    self.currentTime["hr"] += Math.floor(self.currentTime["min"] / 60);
    self.currentTime["sec"] = self.currentTime["sec"] % 60;
    self.currentTime["min"] = self.currentTime["min"] % 60;
  }

  function getPrintableTime() {
    var text = getTwoDigitNumber(self.currentTime["hr"]) + ":" + getTwoDigitNumber(self.currentTime["min"]) + ":" + getTwoDigitNumber(self.currentTime["sec"]);
    return text;
  }

  function getTwoDigitNumber(number) {
    if (number > 9) {
      return "" + number;
    } else {
      return "0" + number;
    }
  }
};
module.exports = Timer;
```

I have all methods in `start` function. The problem is that for each new object of `Timer`, new space for each method will be used which is very inefficient. But when I try to put methods outside of `start` function, they lose access to `self` variable. You can see that there is `setInterval` function used which will be calling these methods per second. I cannot use `this` also as `this` will be instance of Window in subsequent calls.

How can I solve this situation by only keeping one instance of all the interior methods?

Comment: How are you creating new object of `Timer` and how are you invoking. Can you place example of those. Issue dont appear to be in your code rather appears in your method of invocation.

Comment: So why don't you use a fully prototypal pattern?

Comment: @epascarello dont want to expose other functions.

Comment: You are exposing them with the selected solution!!!! lol

Comment: i changed the selected solution in between. But if you are talking about later selection then please explain how.

Comment: update, render, increment, etc are all exposed. What you said you did not want is what is happening. I can access any of them.

Comment: Can you show me accessing them. I got variable not defined error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply` to use functions defined outside of prototype with correct `this` context.

```js
function Timer(elem) {

  this.interval = null;
  this.currentTime = {
    sec: 0,
    min: 0,
    hr: 0
  };
  this.elem = elem;
};

function update() {
  incrementTime.apply(this);
  render.apply(this);
}

function render() {
  this.elem.innerText = getPrintableTime.apply(this);
}

function incrementTime() {
  this.currentTime["min"] += Math.floor((++this.currentTime["sec"]) / 60);
  this.currentTime["hr"] += Math.floor(this.currentTime["min"] / 60);
  this.currentTime["sec"] = this.currentTime["sec"] % 60;
  this.currentTime["min"] = this.currentTime["min"] % 60;
}

function getPrintableTime() {
  var text = getTwoDigitNumber(this.currentTime["hr"]) + ":" + getTwoDigitNumber(this.currentTime["min"]) + ":" + getTwoDigitNumber(this.currentTime["sec"]);
  return text;
}

function getTwoDigitNumber(number) {
  if (number > 9) {
    return "" + number;
  } else {
    return "0" + number;
  }
}

Timer.prototype.start = function() {
  var self = this;
  if (!self.interval) {
    self.interval = setInterval(function() {
      update.apply(self);
    }, 1000);
  }
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var timer = new Timer(document.getElementById('timer'));
  timer.start();
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: I tried this exactly and it was not working. During subsequent calls to functions, this points to Window instead of Timer

Comment: `this` will point to `Window` only if functions outside of prototype are called without using `apply`.

Comment: this worked. I was using it wrongly earlier. This is exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have *all* methods in the `start` function. Yes,  for each new `Timer` instance, new space for each function will be used, but that is necessary when you want to work with `setInterval` as you need a function which closes over the instance. However, you need only *one* such closure, the other methods can be standard prototype methods.

```
function getTwoDigitNumber(number) {
    return (number > 9 ? "" : "0") + number;
}

function Timer(elem) {
    this.interval = null;
    this.currentTime = {
        sec: 0,
        min: 0,
        hr: 0
    };
    this.elem = elem;
};

Timer.prototype.start = function() {
    var self = this;
    if (!this.interval) {
        this.interval = setInterval(function update() {
            self.incrementTime();
            self.render();
        }, 1000);
    }
};
Timer.prototype.render() {
    this.elem.innerText = this.getPrintableTime();
};
Timer.prototype.incrementTime = function() {
    this.currentTime.sec += 1;
    this.currentTime.min += Math.floor(this.currentTime.sec / 60);
    this.currentTime.hr += Math.floor(this.currentTime.min / 60);
    this.currentTime.sec = this.currentTime.sec % 60;
    this.currentTime.min = this.currentTime.min % 60;
};
Timer.prototype.getPrintableTime = function() {
    var text = getTwoDigitNumber(this.currentTime.hr) + ":"
             + getTwoDigitNumber(this.currentTime.min) + ":"
             + getTwoDigitNumber(self.currentTime.sec);
    return text;
};

module.exports = Timer;
```

Btw, regarding your `incrementTime` pattern, you should have a look at [How to create an accurate timer in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29971898/1048572).

Comment: If only `start` method needs to be "public", exposing other methods in prototype is breaking encapsulation

Comment: @Stubb0rn and doing what the OP wants to do is the same thing, breaking encapsulation....

Comment: @Stubb0rn If you want "private" methods, you can only use static functions that get passed the instance as an argument. Or use an underscore naming convention. All methods are public in JS, but that wasn't the question anyway - it was about putting the common functions on the prototype.

Comment: @Bergi Is there any way to avoid making each function prototype of Timer. Though I didn't want to break encapsulation but just to avoid multiple instances of each method. How to implement other option, using static function getting instance as argument?

Comment: @ShashwatKumar Just like I did with `getTwoDigitNumber` - and instead of passing `number`, pass `self`.

Comment: @Bergi I can pass `this`? But when javascript calls each function after interval, it passes `this` as Window

Comment: @ShashwatKumar I said `self`. Given that the "methods" aren't real methods any more (outside of the prototype) but just plain functions, they don't have a `this`.

Comment: @Bergi thanks. I tried and it worked. I unnecessarily was getting confused. Also thanks for your incrementing suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're wanting to only create one interval.

One possible solution would be to create a static method and variable to manage the `setInterval`. I would note that while this may be more performance friendly, the timers will always start and run on the same count...not from the moment each timer is created. (See example)

Of course, you could capture the current timestamp and calculate the elapsed time from there. But, that's another thread ;)

```js
function Timer(elem) {
  this.interval = null;
  this.currentTime = {
    sec: 0,
    min: 0,
    hr: 0
  };
  this.elem = elem;
};

Timer.subscribe = function(timer) {
  Timer.subscribers = Timer.subscribers || [];
  if (Timer.subscribers.indexOf(timer) === -1) {
    Timer.subscribers.push(timer);
    timer.update.call(timer);
  }
  Timer.checkInterval();
};

Timer.unsubscribe = function(timer) {
  Timer.subscribers = Timer.subscribers || [];
  if (Timer.subscribers.indexOf(timer) !== -1) {
    Timer.subscribers.splice(Timer.subscribers.indexOf(timer), 1);
  }
  Timer.checkInterval();
};

Timer.checkInterval = function() {
  if (!Timer.interval && Timer.subscribers.length > 0) {
    Timer.interval = setInterval(function() {
      Timer.subscribers.forEach(function(item) {
        item.update.call(item);
      });
    }, 1000);
  } else if (Timer.interval && Timer.subscribers.length === 0) {
    clearInterval(Timer.interval);
    Timer.interval = null;
  }
};

Timer.prototype = {
  start: function() {
    Timer.subscribe(this);
  },
  
  stop: function() {
    Timer.unsubscribe(this);
  },
  
  update: function() {
    this.incrementTime();
    this.render();
  },
  
  incrementTime: function() {
    this.currentTime["min"] += Math.floor((++this.currentTime["sec"]) / 60);
    this.currentTime["hr"] += Math.floor(this.currentTime["min"] / 60);
    this.currentTime["sec"] = this.currentTime["sec"] % 60;
    this.currentTime["min"] = this.currentTime["min"] % 60;
  },
  
  render: function() {
    var self = this;

    function getPrintableTime() {
      var text = getTwoDigitNumber(self.currentTime["hr"]) + ":" + getTwoDigitNumber(self.currentTime["min"]) + ":" + getTwoDigitNumber(self.currentTime["sec"]);
      return text;
    }

    function getTwoDigitNumber(number) {
      if (number > 9) {
        return "" + number;
      } else {
        return "0" + number;
      }
    }
    
    this.elem.innerText = getPrintableTime();
  }
};

/**
 *
 */
var timers = document.getElementById('timers');

function addTimer() {
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  var tmr = document.createElement('span');
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  var t = new Timer(tmr);
  
  btn.innerText = 'Stop';
  btn.onclick = function() {
    t.stop();
  };
  
  el.appendChild(tmr);
  el.appendChild(btn);
  timers.appendChild(el);
  
  t.start();
};
```

```html
<div id="timers"></div>

<button onclick="addTimer()">Add Timer</button>
```