# What's different with requestAnimationFrame's timestamp at various / higher refresh rates?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

So I have a running loop:

```
var FRAME_TIME = 1000 / 60;
var lastTime = 0;
var fpsTime = 0;
var fps = 0;

function mainLoop(timestamp) {
    if (timestamp - lastTime >= FRAME_TIME) {
        fps++;
        lastTime = timestamp;
    }

    if (timestamp - fpsTime >= 1000) {
        console.log(fps);
        fps = 0;
        fpsTime = timestamp;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
```

Now, when running with monitor refresh at 60, I get "60" printed in console as expected. But, when running with resfresh at 144, I get "48" = 1/3 of the refresh.

Why? Time is time, right...?

Comment: are you calling mainLoop() once per rendered frame?

Comment: Well it seems your browser cannot keep up with 144fps, so it will render an animation frame only every third monitor update.

Comment: @Bergi It runs 144 fine without any limiting.

Comment: @BenAbraham It is called continously by raf, so 144 times per second.

Comment: @ludolover How do you know it runs at 144 times per second when your counter does not show that?

Comment: @Bergi When increasing the fps variable unconditionally (outside the if-sentence), it will reach 144 before resetting.

Comment: Oh how could I miss that, yes of course. But *why* did you do it conditionally at all?

Comment: @Bergi The point is to limit the number of updates to 60 for all refresh rates.

Comment: No, let the browser determine the number of updates by itself. It won't always be the same. That's exactly what `requestAnimationFrame` was designed to do - get called when the browser is *ready* to render the next frame. Depending on monitor, load, battery, user settings etc. - everything is done for you already. If it wants to go faster, you should let it do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if (timestamp - lastTime >= FRAME_TIME) fps++;` is no good. That means it does not count every frame - it counts whenever `FRAME_TIME` has passed. At 144 fps, that means there are two frames (at 7 ms and 14 ms) before you count the next frame at 21 ms that is after the expected `FRAME_TIME` for 60 fps - 17 ms. That comes down to only every third frame being counted - exactly what you experience.

To fix it, do `fps++` on every invocation:

```
var fpsTime = 0;
var fps = 0;

function mainLoop(timestamp) {
    fps++;
    if (timestamp - fpsTime >= 1000) {
        console.log(fps);
        fps = 0;
        fpsTime = timestamp;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
mainLoop(performance.now());
```

Comment: Yes, I see it now. 144 fps is not enough for measuring 16ms steps when comparing timestamps. But by changing "lastTime = timestamp" to "lastTime += FRAME_TIME" I get 60 fps excactly though... Or do I? Thanks.

Comment: No, it's rather that there are no 16ms steps when running at 144fps. By doing `+= FRAME_TIME`, yes, you'll get to 60fps, as it will run *on average* every 16ms. But I don't see why you would ever want to do that

Comment: I need to pass a constant timedelta for my "pixel perfect physics simulation", so speed will be controlled by hard-limiting the frequency of updates. That's why. :)

Comment: Well, if you want to set the frequency of *updates*, then use `setInterval` (or something [more accurate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29972322/1048572)). Use `requestAnimationFrame` only to *draw* things at the current state.

Comment: The full program also draws every frame etc. I'll stick with raf, but this answer got me to the point where I'm happy, so I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

So I believe the main issue comes down to these lines.

```
if (timestamp - lastTime >= FRAME_TIME) {
    fps++;
    lastTime = timestamp;
}
```

What that is saying is if our current frame time (timestamp - lastTime) is OVER (or equal) to that of an 'ideal' frame (1000ms / 60 [144]), then we count it, otherwise, it's not counted.

If this function is called (once and only once) every frame, then you don't need an if statement, you can simply do "fps++" every frame, because it will be reset by the 1 second counter.

Comment: That if statement is the frame limiter though, and I want to measure the limited frames, not the max.