# Javascript clock - server time

Tags: javascript

I need to show the server time on a clock. Below is the code i currently have. I get the server time with Ajax call. The problem is that if the user changes it's local/computer clock it will also update the script's clock which is not ok - it should continue without changing and i'm stuck. I've tried passing the serverTime within the setTimeout so it get's used every time as a reference but no luck with that.

```js
var serverTime  = 1490856278000;
var localTime   = +Date.now();
var timeDiff    = serverTime - localTime;
var realTime;
var date;
var hours;
var minutes;
var seconds;
setInterval(function () {
  realTime = +Date.now() + timeDiff;
  date     = new Date(realTime);
  hours    = date.getHours();
  minutes  = date.getMinutes();
  seconds  = date.getSeconds();
  document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="clock"></div>
```

Comment: you should periodically query the servers time, not just a single time.

Comment: What is the problem with the user changing his local time? He can always break your page.

Comment: Yeah, but i don't want the clock to change if it does.

Comment: Since your interval is every `1000ms`, you could reasonably expect it to run within a small window of that value. Compare the `Date.now()` you get to whatever `Date.now()` you got last time around, and if it changes by an unexpected amount (more than 1.5s, less than 0.5s, or negative, for example) then re-request the time from the server to recalibrate.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Seems as a good option, thanks

Comment: Btw, you probably will want to use `getUTCHours`, `getUTCMinutes` and `getUTCSeconds` instead of the local ones that could be tinkered with already by a changing time zone.

Comment: Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to compare each `realTime` with the last one in your `setInterval`. If the difference is far from the 1000ms that it is supposed to be, do an ajax call to query the server time again and renew the `timeDiff`.

---

Also you can try to use [`performance.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) instead of `Date.now`. The higher resolution is unnecessary and possibly expensive, but MDN states that

> unlike `Date.now()`, the values returned by `Performance.now()` always increase at a constant rate, independent of the system clock (which might be adjusted manually or skewed by software like NTP)

Comment: Oh, I found an even better solution for reasonably modern browsers :-)

Comment: Thanks @Bergi for your solution and additional tips :)

Answer (score 2):

Using [How to create an accurate timer in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971898/how-to-create-an-accurate-timer-in-javascript/29972322#29972322) and Bergi's answer I prepared an another way. I think you don't have to use the local time at all:

```js
var serverTime  = 1490856278000;
var expected = serverTime;
var date;
var hours;
var minutes;
var seconds;
var now = performance.now();
var then = now;
var dt = 0;
var nextInterval = interval = 1000; // ms

setTimeout(step, interval);
function step() {
    then = now;
    now = performance.now();
    dt = now - then - nextInterval; // the drift
    
    nextInterval = interval - dt;
    serverTime += interval;
    date     = new Date(serverTime);
    hours    = date.getUTCHours();
    minutes  = date.getUTCMinutes();
    seconds  = date.getUTCSeconds();
    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;

    console.log(nextInterval, dt); //Click away to another tab and check the logs after a while
    now = performance.now();

    setTimeout(step, Math.max(0, nextInterval)); // take into account drift
}
```

```html
<div id="clock"></div>
```

Comment: The problem with that is that [`setInterval` drifts away](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29972322/1048572).

Comment: Ach, ok. I'll try to adjust my answer, not sure if we need that local time.

Comment: Using server time only seems like a quick and easy solution. @Bergi you think it can drift away in 15 minutes badly? I plan to refresh the page every 15 min.

Comment: @g5wx If the tab is not active (in background), yes it can happen, otherwise you will hardly notice. But I thought the whole point of making pages interactive with JS is so that you *don't* need to constantly refresh them :-)

Comment: Hehe, yes it is :)

Comment: Thanks @Oskar for your solution.

Comment: @Bergi What if we use the performance.now() for computing the dt and adjusting the time interval?

Comment: @g5wx the pleasure is mine, I learned something new today thanks to your question, I also updated my answer, but not sure if it helps with dt.

Comment: @Oskar Yes, you can use the "accurate timer" approach with `performance.now` as well

Comment: @Bergi, I just checked and fixed my code to be more reliable and drift-proof, when I click away from the SO tab it shows the correct time. You can check the dt in console.log. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: but when will then = now?!

Answer (score 0):

The time *will* change because `Date.now();` is getting it's time from the Client machine. There are no AJAX calls in your script.

Answer (score 0):

More Updated with AM & PM

```
var serverTime = 1490856278000;
    var expected = serverTime;
    var date;
    var h;
    var m;
    var s;
    var now = performance.now();
    var then = now;
    var dt = 0;
    var nextInterval = (interval = 1000);

    setTimeout(step, interval);
    function step() {
      then = now;
      now = performance.now();
      dt = now - then - nextInterval;
      nextInterval = interval - dt;
      serverTime += interval;
      date = new Date(serverTime);
      h = date.getHours();
      m = date.getMinutes();
      s = date.getSeconds();

      var session = "AM";

      if (h == 0) {
        h = 12;
      }

      if (h > 12) {
        h = h - 12;
        session = "PM";
      }

      h = h < 10 ? "0" + h : h;
      m = m < 10 ? "0" + m : m;
      s = s < 10 ? "0" + s : s;

      var time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + session;

      document.getElementById("NowTime").innerHTML = time;

      now = performance.now();

      setTimeout(step, Math.max(0, nextInterval));
    }
```