# Running a task every seond in node.js lags

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to run a job every second in node.js.
First I tried to use setInterval, then I tried later.js https://www.npmjs.com/package/later

But when I try to run my job with both of these ways, I have the same problem: there is a lag in about 2-3 milliseconds.

I placed console.log(new Date()) in my job and it shows that every next calling of my job happens 2-3 milliseconds later than the previous one.

What is the best and precise way of running a job every second in node.js?

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` instead, and at the end of the task check the clock and schedule the next one. That said, getting a timer to go off within 2 to 3 milliseconds of when you want it is probably about the best you can expect.

Comment: @Pointy maybe there is some library for that? I searched a long time for that, but cant find a goob lib for that problem.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=precision+timer

Comment: If your code isn't running on a real-time OS, there's only so much that Node can do.

Comment: @robertklep unfortunately among offered libs there is no suitable one.

Comment: @StasCoder why not?

Comment: Most of the libraries found by @robertklep are for time measurement, not for event timing.  The rest are either web-based, or fall back to the JS engine and use math to adjust for "drift".  The core problem is that JS engines run in an event loop, and there's no "interrupt handling" available.  Callbacks are only called "between" event loops.  It might be possible to build a native library to do the job, but I'd only give it a 50/50 chance.

Comment: [`rolex`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rolex) offers an interval timer with drift limiting that outperforms `setInterval`. I think it's as good as you're going to get (with _any_ interpreted language, possibly).

Comment: the best solution I found is https://gist.github.com/manast/1185904

Comment: I think you can use the solution here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971898/how-to-create-an-accurate-timer-in-javascript