# How to make an html5 player play without a source

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, media-player, video.js

I am building a multimedia player that needs to control multiple **other** multimedia players on a page. In order to do that I want to have an area at the bottom of the page which contains a media playback controller (**including a seekbar**) that will control all other players on the page. For example, when a user hits the play button all the other players on the page starts playing.

I want to use a regular video/audio player, but instead of playing real content all I want is to have the controls, especially a seekbar which advances. The reason for not implementing playback controls on my own is because I want to use the power of **video.js** plugins (like event markers on the timeline).

I have managed to display a **video.js** player **only** with playback controls. In addition I have managed to set the duration. The problem is that the player doesn't play when I hit the play button nor calilng `player.play()`.

This is because the player doesn't have a media source. video.js and the native player won't play without a media source.

Now, is there a way to force a player to play even without a source? Can I make it think it has one?

Thank you,

Comment: You could always use javascript to check if your **html5 player** has a source. If it hasn't one, the **html5 player** is _done playing the video_. I can provide an example if needed.

Comment: You missed all the point, I don't want to have a source, I want a player that can play without a media source. That way I get the functionality of a multimedia player without having to have video or audio content.

Comment: When you say "_I want a player that can play without a media source_", what do you want it to play? In my opinion, if you don't have any content, it's fine to assume that that empty **html5 player** is done playing its content.

Comment: Again, I want to use the playback controls from a multimedia player (seekbar, play button, pause button an so on..) that will control multiple **other** players which are presented on the page. Instead of implementing the functionality myself  I want to use the browser's audio/video player. Apparently I can't make a seekbar of player without any content to advance. **This is my question** - Can I somehow make a video/audio player play without any content?

Comment: In that case, you can't. The best thing to do in this situation is to feed the **html5 player** with a blank source (black screen) through javascript (if the player has no source).

Comment: Can you supply me with an example or direction on how to create a blank source? I have tried to create an empty `MediaSource` which is fed from an empty `ArrayBuffer` but with no success. I suspect I need to supply information like mp4/mp3 metadata in the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out a solution that works.

Again **the purpose is having working media controllers from video.js without loading any media content and the most important controller is the seek bar.**

I have been playing with **video.js** and was trying to make the seek bar advance without loading any media content and found out that calling `player.currentTime()` does actually updates the `curretTime` internal member but doesn't update the UI.

Eventually I found out that in order to make **video.js** update the UI we need to trigger the `timeupdate` event.

So I decided to implement a fake player that has control over all the other players and uses a **video.js** player as his UI (by showing only the media controls and hiding the video).

**The fake player need to use a precise timer as mentioned** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971898/how-to-create-an-accurate-timer-in-javascript).

**Conceptual example:**

```
import videojs from 'video.js';

class MainMediaController {
    public static readonly INTERVAL = 250;

    protected _playerId: string;
    protected _duration: number;
    protected _mediaController: videojs.Player;
    protected _childPlayers: videojs.Player[];
    protected _currentTime: number;

    private _interval: number;
    private _intervalId: number;

    constructor(playerId: string, recordingDuration: number, childPlayers: videojs.Player[]) {
        this._playerId = playerId;          // id of the player at the bottom of the page which will be served as the main timeline
        this._duration = recordingDuration;
        this._interval = MainMediaController.INTERVAL;
        this._childPlayers = childPlayers;
        this._currentTime = 0;
}

    public async init() {
        this._mediaController = videojs(this._playerId);

        // await for ready state
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this._mediaController.ready(() => {
                resolve();
            });
        });

        // set duration for a correct seek bar (longest.endTime - first.startTime)
        this._mediaController.duration(this._duration);
    }

    public play(){
        // update UI every 250ms
        this._intervalId = setInterval(this.intervalStep.bind(this), this._interval);

        for(let player of this._childPlayers){
            player.play();
        }
    }

    private intervalStep(){
        this._currentTime += 0.250;                          // 250ms
        this._mediaController.currentTime(this._currentTime);
        this._mediaController.trigger("timeupdate");         // trigger() is accessible don't worry
    }

    public pause(){...}
    public stop(){...}
    public seek(){...}
}
```

**That solution let me use video.js plugins in my main timeline that has no video in it!!**

Comment: I've looked everywhere for something like this, but unfortunately I can't get your code to work. How are the play/pause methods triggered? The master controls do nothing for me still. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's the same principle for images. If you don't have an image for some content, you need to have a backup plan : a placeholder image.

You can do the same with videos.

The simplest solution is to have in your project directory :

```
> placeholders
  |-- fakeVideo_short.mp4
  |-- fakeVideo-long.mp4
  |-- fakeAudio.mp3
  |-- ...
```

Whenever your upper **media controller** finds an empty player, you can just feed it a placeholder content.

It's an easy solution that allows you to focus more quickly on wants important : The **media controller**.

### How to detect if a player needs a placeholder?

Well :

1. Whenever a player finishes/consumes some content, if there is no more content available, you can feed it a placeholder.
2. At the start of the *app*, if there are more players than there is content, you can feed a blank content (placeholders) to the empty players.

Comment: I can't afford to make a fake video each time. What I am trying to implement is a player which synchronizes multiple multimedia files. For example, to play 4 video files (Assuming all of them were recorded briefly in the same time) you load them to my application, and you will be given a matrix and a main media controller underneath the matrix. All I want is a functional media controller which will be taken from video.js, a one with a seekbar that can advance without a real content from behind the scenes

Comment: Oh! No need to have multiple **fakeVideo** files. You just need one video file, let's say 3 seconds of black screen, and you loop it over and over again until some new content is available. I've used **video.js** in the past and I don't think it offers the functionality of controlling multiple videos through a player. You need to build your own media controllers (play, stop, etc).

Comment: Lets say the first video started at 00:03  and last video ended at 00:09, In that cast I want a blank video that will last 00:12 seconds. How can I load a 3 seconds blank video and make the player play is for 12 seconds?

Comment: I think that you should change the title to "How to simulate a continuous flow of video content on the client-side" or ask another question for the **length of the video** part. It seems like you want to generate some video placeholder in between actual live uploaded videos. This process should be done on a server and your app should listen to it. This way, you only need one player.