# How do I accurately setState on a time delay?

Tags: javascript, react-native, setinterval, setstate

I am trying to `setState` on a given time interval (100ms). I have discovered both in practice and through research that `setInterval` is inaccurate, and will float over time. I need it to be accurate because I'm aiming to have data (from an array) in my app synced up to a video.

Here is what I currently have:

```
data = this.processCSV(text);
    let idx = 0
    this.intOne = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(previousState => (
        {
          data1: parseFloat(data[idx][2]),
          data2: parseFloat(data[idx][1]),
          data3: parseFloat(data[idx][3])
        }
      ));
      idx = idx + 1;
      }, 100);
```

In my research, I've found a few solutions that use `Date` to accurately keep track of time and account for drifting.

Expected Results: `setState` is called 10 times per second for an extended amount of time

Current Results: `setState` is called ~9 times per second and continues to float away from expected time

Comment: No web api provides you such a guarantees. Even worse - given your application runs in a non rtos, the guarantees simply cannot be given.

Comment: Is there anything that can get me close? I guess a perfect guarantee is unrealistic, but having something better than setInterval would be nice.

Comment: what if you rethink the whole problem: instead of relying on number of ticks, you rely on the current video timeline and infer your state from it.

Comment: I like the idea, not sure how I would achieve this though...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an accurate timer in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971898/how-to-create-an-accurate-timer-in-javascript)

Comment: This library seems to be keeping an accurate count and limits drifting: https://www.npmjs.com/package/accurate-interval

Comment: @redsoxfan, what exact issue do you have trying to implement self-correcting timer?

Comment: I was having trouble because I kept getting an error that setState wasn’t a function. And I was having trouble figuring out where to put “.bind(this)” but figured it out