# How can I stop this canvas animation drawing new particles after 5 seconds and restart it from zero particles on click?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html5-canvas

I would like to stop drawing new particles after 5 seconds and restart drawing on click anywhere.

Here is the code https://codepen.io/Jeremboo/pen/ENVaMY for the animation.

Right now it keeps on drawing until you click on the screen to restart it again.

What I want is to stop drawing after 5 seconds and then on click anywhere restart it from zero particles. I tried the following to stop but I am not able to start it again.

this is the js code

```
/**/ const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
/**/ const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
/**/ let windowWidth = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
/**/ let windowHeight = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
/**/ canvas.id = 'canvas';
/**/ document.body.insertBefore(canvas, document.body.firstChild);
/**/ /* ---- CORE END ---- */
/* ---- CREATING ZONE ---- */

/* ---- SETTINGS ---- */
const numberParticlesStart = 1000;
const particleSpeed = 0.3;
const velocity = 0.9;
const circleWidth = 50;

/* ---- INIT ---- */
let particles = [];

const getRandomFloat = (min, max) => (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);


/* ---- Particle ---- */
function Particle (x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;

  this.vel = {
    x : getRandomFloat(-20, 20)/100,
    y : getRandomFloat(-20, 20)/100,
    min : getRandomFloat(2, 10),
    max : getRandomFloat(10, 100)/10
  }

  this.color = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)';
}
Particle.prototype.render = function() {
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = this.color;
  context.arc(this.x, this.y, 1, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  context.fill();
};
Particle.prototype.update = function() {

  const forceDirection = {
    x: getRandomFloat(-1, 1),
    y: getRandomFloat(-1, 1),
  };

  if (Math.abs(this.vel.x + forceDirection.x) < this.vel.max) {
    this.vel.x += forceDirection.x;
  }
  if (Math.abs(this.vel.y + forceDirection.y) < this.vel.max) {
    this.vel.y += forceDirection.y;
  }

  this.x += this.vel.x * particleSpeed;
  this.y += this.vel.y * particleSpeed;

  if (Math.abs(this.vel.x) > this.vel.min) {
    this.vel.x *= velocity;
  }
  if (Math.abs(this.vel.y) > this.vel.min) {
    this.vel.y *= velocity;
  }

  this.testBorder();
};
Particle.prototype.testBorder = function() {
  if (this.x > windowWidth) {
    this.setPosition(this.x, 'x');
  } else if (this.x < 0) {
    this.setPosition(windowWidth, 'x');
  }
  if (this.y > windowHeight) {
    this.setPosition(this.y, 'y');
  } else if (this.y < 0) {
    this.setPosition(windowHeight, 'y');
  }
};
Particle.prototype.setPosition = function(pos, coor) {
  if (coor === 'x') {
    this.x = pos;
  } else if (coor === 'y') {
    this.y = pos;
  }
};

/* ---- Functions ----*/
function loop() {
  let i;
  const length = particles.length;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    particles[i].update();
    particles[i].render();
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

/* ---- START ---- */
function init() {
  let i;
  for (i = 0; i < numberParticlesStart; i++) {
    const angle = Math.random() * 360;
    particles.push(new Particle(
      windowWidth * 0.5 + (Math.cos(angle) * circleWidth),
      windowHeight * 0.5 - (Math.sin(angle) * circleWidth),
  ));
  }
}
init();
window.onresize = () => {
   windowWidth = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
   windowHeight = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
   particles = [];
   context.clearRect(0,0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
   init();
}

window.addEventListener('click', () => {
  particles = [];
  context.clearRect(0,0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
  init();
});

loop();
```

i replaced the function loop() with this to stop it after 5 seconds -

```
function loop(stp) {
  let i;
  const length = particles.length;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    particles[i].update();
    particles[i].render();
  }
if (stp > 5000) return;
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To improve this question you can add your code as a [runnable snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @CharlieWallace I tried using that but its not generating any output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rely on system clock, as `setTimeout` and `setInterval` [are not accurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971898/how-to-create-an-accurate-timer-in-javascript)

```
let start;
function loop(startTime) {
  let i;
  if(startTime){
     // Set the current time in milliseconds from 1st of jenuary 1970
     start = new Date().getTime();
  }
  const length = particles.length;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    particles[i].update();
    particles[i].render();
  }
// Comparison from current dateTime with the stored one
// as setInterval and setTimeout are not accurate
if (start - (new Date().getTime() >= 5000) return;
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
loop(true);
```

Comment: Hi @Mosè Raguzzini , i tried your suggestion but it breaks the loop and stop drawing any new particles.

Comment: I don't have tested the snippet as the code is incomplete, what's your error ?

Comment: Thanks @Mosè Raguzzini  It Stops after 5 seconds but did not start again on click anywhere on screen which it does in its original code.

Comment: You have to relaunch loop(true) on click

Comment: New edited snippet: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JVbKWy  I've moved loop(true) at the end of the init() function