# Why do two seemingly identical JS functions run differently?

Tags: javascript

I just created a simple JavaScript counter. The first version adds a constant every second to an initial value; the second version adds 1 to the initial value in a proportionately reduced amount of time. I'm not rounding any numbers. But if you let the counter run long enough, the resulting values start diverging considerably. Any idea why that is?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var Today = new Date();
  var Jan = new Date("January 1 2020 00:00");
  var dif = (Today.getTime() - Jan.getTime()) / 1000;
  const Clklid = 3.55988;
  var new1 = Clklid * dif;
  var new2 = Clklid * dif;
  var text = document.getElementById("text")
  var text2 = document.getElementById("text2")


  setInterval(function() {
    new1 += Clklid;
    // new1 = Math.trunc(new1);
    text.innerHTML = new1 + " g emisí CO2";
  }, 1000);

  setInterval(function() {
    new2 += 1;
    // new2 = Math.trunc(new2);
    text2.innerHTML = new2 + " g emisí CO2";
  }, 1000 / Clklid);
}
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
<div id="text2"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6t4b1sqk/

Comment: Note that interval timers use **integer** millisecond counters, and they're not very accurate.

Comment: setTimeout and setInterval are not accurate, use dates instead. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971898/how-to-create-an-accurate-timer-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an accurate timer in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971898/how-to-create-an-accurate-timer-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

`setInterval` is not perfect and actually takes up to 5 milliseconds longer for each iteration. Intervals that update more often will be behind one that update less.

If you want the 2 timers to always show similar values, only use one counter (replace `new1` and `new2` with `new`)
Alternatively, have both counters update in one function and not in the other:

```
setInterval(function() {
  new1 += Clklid;
  new2 += 1;
  // new1 = Math.trunc(new1);
  // new2 = Math.trunc(new2);
  text.innerHTML = new1 + " g emisí CO2";
}, 1000);

setInterval(function() {
  // new2 = Math.trunc(new2);
  text2.innerHTML = new2 + " g emisí CO2";
}, 1000 / Clklid);
```