# Complex Timers in javascript and design pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, timer

I'm currently building an app that is an overlay to a game. This app takes in game events and creates objects to make timers. Every timer is different depending on what events the app took from the game. What is the best design pattern for this situation?

this is the timer and the other one is a function that writes in a html file

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration;
    var minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

var writeSum = function(sums, champ){
    var height = "height: 25px;";  
    var width = "width: 25px;";
    var size = "background-size: 25px 25px;";
    var image = "background-image: url( '../../icons/summoner spells/"+sums.path + "\' );";
    var display = "display: inline;";
    var click = "onclick =\"startTimer("+ sums.cd+", document.getElementById('"+ champ.name+ sums.name+"'\)\)\" ";

    return tag("div","",tag("button", click+style(height+width+image+size),"")+ tag("p","id = \""+champ.name+ sums.name + "\" "+style(display),"Ready"));
};
```

Comment: There is no "design pattern" that applies to your situation. You'll need to engineer a genuine design.

Comment: I ask this because I can't figure out a way to create a button that resets/starts a timer without having the old timer on at the same time while having multiple timers.

Comment: Just have the button either overwrite the old timer or add a new timer to the list, depending on which you want. It would be easier to answer your question if you could specify a concrete behaviour of a button that you cannot achieve, and the code you tried. It's even unclear what the term "timer" refers to exactly.

Comment: have a look, its part of the code

Comment: Ah ok. Well, first of all, switch to using the DOM instead of building html strings. That'll allow you to attach event listeners using functions, and then you can easily attach different functions (built using closures) to different buttons.

Comment: FYI setTimeout/interval are not very accurate.

Comment: is there a more accurate way for time?

Comment: basically just check current time for timer resolution (`new Date().getTime()`).  check google: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971898/how-to-create-an-accurate-timer-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple demo of keeping track of multiple timers with an array of objects.  Just decide on a well-formed structure that is easy to work with to represent your data model.  Be it classes or functions or plain objects.

I strongly recommend refactoring your string building.  Especially the `onclick=` with JavaScript code generated through string concatenation.  And ideally you need to keep track of timers, which startTimer should return and should be mergeable into and transformable with your data structure for representing each timer.
Right now it looks like you'd probably end up devolving into using globals to pass parameters around.
If it's just a simple task, keeping a global list of timers probably isn't a big deal.

```js
tag = (x,y,z)=>`<${x} ${y||''}>${z||''}</${x}>`


    function startTimer(duration, display) {
        var timer = duration;
        var minutes, seconds;
        setInterval(function () {
            minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
            seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

            display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

            if (--timer < 0) {
                timer = duration;
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    var writeSum = function(sums, champ){
        var height = "height: 25px;";  
        var width = "width: 25px;";
        var size = "background-size: 25px 25px;";
        var image = "background-image: url( '../../icons/summoner spells/"+sums.path + "\' );";
        var display = "display: inline;";
        var click = "onclick =\"startTimer("+ sums.cd+", document.getElementById('"+ champ.name+ sums.name+"'\)\)\" ";

        return tag("div","",tag("button", click+style(height+width+image+size),"")+ tag("p","id = \""+champ.name+ sums.name + "\" "+style(display),"Ready"));
    };

    function style(x){return `style="${x}"`}

let entities = [
    {sums: {path:'spath1',cd:'10',name:'sname1'}, champ: {name:'cname1'}},
    {sums: {path:'spath2',cd:'10',name:'sname2'}, champ: {name:'cname2'}},
    {sums: {path:'spath3',cd:'10',name:'sname3'}, champ: {name:'cname3'}},
    {sums: {path:'spath4',cd:'10',name:'sname4'}, champ: {name:'cname4'}}
]
document.body.innerHTML=entities.map(({sums, champ})=>writeSum(sums, champ)).join('')
```