# setTimeout different results in Node.js and Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer

I am trying to understand this piece of code but I get different results in different runtime environment:
The condition:

1. Print "Hello World" Every second
2. And stop after 5 times
3. After 5 times. Print "Done" and let Node exit.

```js
let timerId = setInterval(() => console.log("Hello world"), 1000);

// after 5 seconds stop
setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(timerId);
  console.log("Done");
}, 5000);
```

In Node.js, this is printed in terminal:

[image]

The message is printed 4 times, not 5 times!

In browser's console, it is fine:

[image]

But when I add debugger to the code and run in browser, I get a completely different result:
[image]

Any clarification is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

There’s a host of question/answers on this out there. See for example [How to create an accurate timer in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971898/how-to-create-an-accurate-timer-in-javascript)
which discusses trying to create an accurate timer using setInterval and setTimeout.

> Why is it not accurate? Because you are using setTimeout() or
> setInterval(). They cannot be trusted, there are no accuracy
> guarantees for them. They are allowed to lag arbitrarily, and they do
> not keep a constant pace but tend to drift (as you have observed).

You are at the mercy of a lot of factors, not least what else is going on at the same time.

Comment: Could someone explain why this has been down voted? Is it inaccurate, ie are setInterval and setTimeout accurate? No they are not.