# Round to closest multiple of fraction (worded terribly)

Tags: javascript

Say I have this code for a simple timer:

```js
var a = document.getElementById("a")
var start = Date.now()
window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(()=>{
    a.innerHTML = ((Date.now() - start)/1000).toFixed(3)
  }, 1)
}
```

```html
<p id="a">0.000</p>
```

I've always wanted a timer that counts in multiples of 1/30, so therefore it would go `.033, .067, .100, .167,` etc. I cannot modify the `setInterval` just to do this because of how inaccurate it is, so how can I round what the current time is so that the decimal ends in a valid value?
I know this is terribly worded, I apologize

Comment: The wording is fine.  This makes perfect sense.  :-)  Just multiply everything by 30, do integer math, and divide back out again for your displayed decimal value.

Comment: See also [How to create an accurate timer in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29971898/1048572)

Comment: Like @Brad said, `(Math.floor(diff * 30 / 1000) / 30).toFixed(3)` should do

Comment: Perfect! This works great, thanks so much