# Javascript setInterval working in local but on the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, settimeout, setinterval

I am using `Angular 10` and have the following `setInterval` code working in my local:

```
ngOnInit() {
         this.myfunc();
         setInterval(this.myfunc.bind(this), 120000);
}
```

However, the same code is not working on the server.
In other words, `myfunc()` is not triggering after `2 mins` when running on the server.

> Debugging Details:

In my local, `this.myfunc()` is called when the component is loaded for the first time. It is called again after `2 mins` as per the `setInterval()`

However, when running on the server, `this.myfunc()` is called when the component is loaded for the first time. But it is `not` called again after `2 mins` as per the `setInterval()`

Comment: setInterval sometimes drifts. Have you accounted for drifting?

Comment: No, I haven't. Can you suggest how it can be accounted?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971898/how-to-create-an-accurate-timer-in-javascript try this

Comment: can you please suggest how the updated code will look like in my case? thanks

Comment: would you like me to make you an answer post?

Comment: yes please. that will be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by changing `setInterval()` to callback as follows:

```
setInterval(() => {
    this.myfunc(); }, 120000);
```

}

Updated `ngOnInit()` looks as below:

```
ngOnInit() {
         this.myfunc();
         setInterval(() => {
         this.myfunc(); }, 120000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

`setInterval` sometimes drifts, as seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971898/how-to-create-an-accurate-timer-in-javascript).

## Solution

Taken from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44337628/13759058), you would first make a non-drifting class:

```js
function AdjustingInterval(workFunc, interval) {
         let that = this;
         let expected, timeout;
         this.interval = interval;

         this.start = function() {
                  expected = Date.now() + this.interval;
                  timeout = setTimeout(step, this.interval);
         }

         this.stop = function() {
                  clearTimeout(timeout);
         }

         function step() {
                  let drift = Date.now() - expected;
                  workFunc();
                  expected += that.interval;
                  timeout = setTimeout(step, Math.max(0, that.interval - drift));
         }
}
```

and then, you would just use this instead for your code:

```js
ngOnInit() {
         let ticker = new AdjustingInterval(this.myfunc.bind(this), 120000);
         this.myfunc();
         ticker.start();
}
```