# Hello, i am working with javascript and i was wondering if there is an event listener for passing time, e.g. a timer

Tags: javascript, timer, addeventlistener

i am working with javascript and i was wondering if there is an event listener for passing time, e.g. a timer. I currently have an event listener in place for a mouse click, but i would like to remove the ability for GUI to control when the event happens.

I have this code right now for the event listener.

```
function doubleClick(e) {
    for (var i = gravities.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (gravities[i].isMouseOver) {
            gravities[i].collapse();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am relatively new at javascript, and don’t know how to make another line of code that would execute the function, but on a timed schedule i.e. every 30 seconds as opposed to on user input.

Comment: [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971898/how-to-create-an-accurate-timer-in-javascript

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an accurate timer in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971898/how-to-create-an-accurate-timer-in-javascript)