# Scheduling thousands of events in Javascript animation

Tags: javascript, animation, settimeout, setinterval

I have a file (about 10'000 lines) containing the trajectory of my mouse pointer, in the form of a sequence of 2D coordinates and times, like so:

```
x1,y1,t1
x2,y2,t2
...
```

The meaning of line `k` is the following: *the pointer was at `(xk,yk)` at time `tk`*.

The times `t1,t2,...` are measured in milliseconds. The difference between two consecutive times is not necessarily constant, can be large or go down to below 10 milliseconds.

I want to reproduce this trajectory as an animation in a browser, by having javascript move a small image around, following the above rule. It is important that this be very accurate since it should be synchronized with an audio recording.

I understand that one way of doing is to compute the time differences between the successive positions, and to use `setTimeout()`. But since the differences can sometimes be under 10 milliseconds, I am afraid that this will lead to some inaccuracies that could pile up as the animation goes. Since the time intervals aren't of constant lenghts `setInterval` doesn't seem appropriate either.

Is there a better way of doing this? How can one ask javascript to run a certain function at very specific times `t1,t2,t3,...,t10000` to ensure the best possible accuracy?

Comment: See [How to create an accurate timer in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29971898/1048572). Instead of adding a fixed `interval` to `expected`, you just get the next timestamp from your list.

Comment: Depends. Did you actually *try* the `setTimeout` approach? Or is this just speculative? If it's not just speculative and you really do have issues, you could a) use rAF and poll `Date.now`. Still not guaranteed, but likely higher resolution than just `setTimeout`. Or you could write it in C++ and compile to WASM with emscripten. Again not guaranteed, but higher res.

Comment: 10ms accuracy is unreasonable. At 60fps, one frame takes slightly more than 16ms. To be able to run at or close to 60fps, use [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: @Ouroborus OP doesn't actually try to achieve 10ms resolution accuracy, he only needs to prevent accumulating error ("*I am afraid that this will lead to some inaccuracies that could pile up*" - and rightly so).