# P5.JS - Action every few seconds

Tags: javascript, loops, processing, draw, p5.js

I am quite new to p5 and would need some advice.

Is it possible to trigger an action only every few seconds?
For example: After two seconds i++;

If I use draw() or an own loop function it just goes way to fast.

Thanks a lot.
Max

Comment: Sure, it's possible. Every `draw()` invocation could test `Date.now()` against a cached `lastFired` date, and if it's greater than `x` seconds, save the new `lastFired` and do the thing you want to do every `x` seconds. Could you share your code so far as a [mcve], please?

Comment: Thank you. That's a big brain solution. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of `setInterval(function, delay)` as shown below:

```js
let counter = 0;

function increment() {
  counter++;
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  setInterval(increment, 2000); // 2000 ms = every 2 seconds
  fill(0);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  text(counter, 100, 100);
}
```

I have set up an Example Sketch for you [here](https://editor.p5js.org/WaldemarLehner/sketches/htSafoQg3).

You can read more about setInterval on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)

Comment: Wow, that's handy. Didn't know sth. like this exists in P5. Why isn't it mentioned in their references?

Comment: `setInterval(increment, 2000); // 2000 ms = every 2 seconds` is somewhat misleading. The 2000 parameter to `setInterval` means "re-call at least 2 seconds after the last call". The delays will accrue and begin to drift over time. `Date` gives you a mechanism to correct the drift, and you'll probably want to poll `Date` inside `draw()` which is a tight `requestAnimationFrame` loop.

Comment: @Skaend It's not mentioned because it's not part of P5.js, but rather a feature of JS.

Comment: @ggorlen But why does it drift over time? I dont get that

Comment: That's how it was designed. If the contract is "fire this at least 2 seconds from now", the script might get bogged down doing other heavy tasks and it might not fire for 2.1 seconds. Now all subsequent calls are off, and maybe the next one after that won't fire for 2.3 seconds after the last one. leading to .4 seconds of drift that just keeps getting worse. There is no timer that internally corrects this. See [How to create an accurate timer in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971898/how-to-create-an-accurate-timer-in-javascript/29972322#29972322)