# Office.js callback for timeout events

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We are using [ExecuteFunction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/action?view=common-js-preview#xsitype) to call functions in our Add-In one a button click.

We are facing the issue that it's possible that the function takes more than 5min to execute. Which seems to be the hard timeout limit.

Is there a way to get at least notified about the timeout in a callback or something?

```
// Commands.js:
const replyAction = async (event: Office.AddinCommands.Event) => {
    // Long running code
    ...

    event.completed(). // this never gets called
}

window.replyAction = replyAction;
```

```
// manifest.xml
<Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
   <FunctionName>composeAction</FunctionName>
</Action>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to get at least notified about the timeout in a callback or something?

The Office JavaScript API doesn't provide anything for that out of the box. You can use your own timer to calculate the timeout, see [How to create an accurate timer in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971898/how-to-create-an-accurate-timer-in-javascript) for more information.

Note, you can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.

> // Long running code

If your long-running code is related to extracting the data from Office/Outlook you may consider using the launch event for pre-fetching the required data if required. See [Configure your Outlook add-in for event-based activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch?tabs=xmlmanifest#supported-events) for more information.

Also you may consider opening a task pane instead of executing a function. In case of task pane you may run a time-consuming functions without issues.

Comment: Thanks! Not the answer I was hoping for, though :(