# clearTimeout doesn't work when the timeout function is calling itself

Tags: javascript

I am using the code for accurate timer from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29972322/17490329

but I modified it to be a countdown timer.

I want that when the countdown ends, it will stop, but using `clearTimeout` in my case doesn't work:

```js
let duration = 5; // seconds
countdownTimer(duration);

function countdownTimer (duration) {
    let interval = 1000; // milliseconds 
    let expected = Date.now() + interval;
    let timeoutHandler;

    setTimeout(step, interval);
    function step() {
        let dt = Date.now() - expected;
        if (dt > interval) {

        }
        console.log(duration);

        expected += interval;

        duration--;
        if (duration <= 0) {            
            clearTimeout(timeoutHandler); // doesn't stop the timer
        }
        timeoutHandler = setTimeout(step, Math.max(0, interval - dt)); // take into account drift
    }
}
```

Why?

Comment: That still doesn't work

Comment: The `clearTimeout` doesn’t do anything. You simply need to _not call_ `setTimeout` again.

Comment: `if (duration > 0) clearTimeout(timeoutHandler); else timeoutHandler = setTimeout(step, Math.max(0, interval - dt));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let duration = 5; // seconds
countdownTimer(duration);

function countdownTimer (duration) {
    let interval = 1000; // milliseconds 
    let expected = Date.now() + interval;
    let timeoutHandler;

    setTimeout(step, interval);
    function step() {
        let dt = Date.now() - expected;
        if (dt > interval) {

        }
        console.log(duration);

        expected += interval;

        duration--;
        if (duration <= 0) {            
            clearTimeout(timeoutHandler); // doesn't stop the timer
            return; //don't forget to stop executing function
        }
        timeoutHandler = setTimeout(step, Math.max(0, interval - dt)); // take into account drift
    }
}
```

inside of "if" condition you miss "return" to stop executing fucntion

Answer (score 1):

> using clearTimeout in my case doesn't work

It works, but then you execute the setTimeout() again, so if you put last line before the if condition you'll get what you want:

```
let duration = 5; // seconds
countdownTimer(duration);

function countdownTimer (duration) {
    let interval = 1000; // milliseconds 
    let expected = Date.now() + interval;
    let timeoutHandler;

    setTimeout(step, interval);
    
    function step() {
        let dt = Date.now() - expected;
        if (dt > interval) {

        }
        console.log(duration);

        expected += interval;
        duration--;
        
        timeoutHandler = setTimeout(step, Math.max(0, interval - dt));
        
        if (duration <= 0) {            
            clearTimeout(timeoutHandler); // doesn't stop the timer
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or use else... `if (duration > 0) clearTimeout(timeoutHandler); else timeoutHandler = setTimeout(step, Math.max(0, interval - dt));`