# timer gets stuck at 1:60 for a second before going to 1:01

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a Rubik's cube scrambler and timer website, and it works fine so far. I have a scrambler, a timer, and a list of times (everything still in development). The timer works fine but the only problem is that when it updates to the next minute and resets the second count, for example it is at `0:59` then it should go to `1:00` but instead it goes to `1:60` before going to `1:01`. Any help would be appreciated!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Speedcubing Timer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        * {
            padding:20px;
        }
        #times-list-template {
            height:20vh;
            max-height: 20vh;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }
        .hidden {
            display:none;
        }
        #timer-info-box {
            position:fixed;
            bottom:90vh;
            height:10vh;
            background-color:gray;
            padding:5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>CubeTimer v1.0</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <h1>Scramble</h1>
            <h3 id="scramble"></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <h1>Timer<i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info" id="timer-info"></i></h1>
            <h3 id="timer"><span id="minutes"></span>:<span id="seconds"></span></h3>
            <button onclick="list_time()" class="btn btn-primary">Save to list</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <div id="timer-info-box" class="hidden"><p>Press the spacebar to start the timer!</p></div>
            <h1>Times</h1>
            <div id="times-list"><ol id="times-list-template"></ol></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c63b6d877c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
let scramble = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
function scramble_translator() {
    let scramble = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
    if (scramble <= 1) {
        scramble = 'R '
    } else if (scramble > 1 && scramble <= 2) {
        scramble = 'R\' '
    } else if (scramble > 2 && scramble <= 3) {
        scramble = 'U '
    } else if (scramble > 3 && scramble <= 4) {
        scramble = 'U\' '
    } else if (scramble > 4 && scramble <= 5) {
        scramble = 'L '
    } else if (scramble > 5 && scramble <= 6) {
        scramble = 'L\' '
    } else if (scramble > 6 && scramble <= 7) {
        scramble = 'F '
    } else if (scramble > 7 && scramble <= 8) {
        scramble = 'F\' '
    } else if (scramble > 8 && scramble <= 9) {
        scramble = 'D '
    } else if (scramble > 9 && scramble <= 10) {
        scramble = 'D\' '
    } else if (scramble > 10 && scramble <= 11) {
        scramble = 'B '
    } else if (scramble > 11 && scramble <= 12) {
        scramble = 'B\' '
    }

    document.getElementById('scramble').innerHTML += scramble;
}
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    scramble_translator();
}
document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = 0;
document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = 0;
let intervalId;
let minutes = 0;
let seconds = 0;

function timer() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        if (event.key === ' ') {
            if (seconds === 0) {
                intervalId = setInterval(function() {
                    seconds++;
                    document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds;

                    if (seconds > 59 || seconds > 60 && seconds > 119 || seconds > 120 && seconds > 179 || seconds > 180 && seconds > 239) {
                        minutes++;
                        document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = minutes;
                        seconds = 0;
                    }
                }, 1000);
            } else {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
            }
        }
    });
}
timer();

function list_time() {
    let new_time = $('#timer').html();
    $('<div>').html(new_time).appendTo('#times-list-template');
    document.getElementById('scramble').innerHTML = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        scramble_translator();
    }
}
document.getElementById('timer-info').addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
    document.getElementById('timer-info-box').classList.remove('hidden');
});
document.getElementById('timer-info').addEventListener('mouseout', (event) => {
    document.getElementById('timer-info-box').classList.add('hidden');
});

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        list_time();
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you describe what this means `if (seconds > 59 || seconds > 60 && seconds > 119 || seconds > 120 && seconds > 179 || seconds > 180 && seconds > 239)`?

Comment: @jabaa it checks if there is about to be a new minute

Comment: No, the condition makes no sense. You can replace it with `if (seconds > 59)`.

Comment: @jabaa yes but that only works for the first minute

Comment: No, that works for every minute. `seconds > 59` is `true` if `seconds > 239` is `true`. There is no value for `seconds` that would require your `if` condition. How could `seconds` reach a value like `239` if it's reset after `59`? Try it out. Choose some values for `seconds` and go through the condition. Either `seconds > 59` is `true` or everything is `false`.

Comment: You would really enjoy learning about the `%` operator (to see how it simplifies extracting minutes from seconds).

Comment: *"but the only problem is that ..."*: that's not the only problem. Try pressing the spacebar at high frequency when the seconds are about to reach 60. ;-)

Comment: @trincot uhh i tried that and it just stopped at 59

Comment: You tried what? Learning about `%`? What did you learn?

Comment: @trincot i was answering about when you said there was another problem

Comment: What I meant that if I do that, the timer starts multiple times, and so the seconds pass quickly after that. This is because `seconds === 0` becomes a true condition once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your attempt, including:

- The condition `if (seconds > 59 || seconds > 60 ...` makes little sense. When `seconds > 59` is true, the rest of the condition will not even be evaluated, since that is enough to have the whole expression evaluate to true. Instead, you would benefit from using arithmetic: there is a remainder operator in JavaScript, so you can easily extract the number of seconds (within a single minute) from a total number of seconds, and from that derive the number of minutes. So I would suggest to just keep increasing `seconds` and then derive the two components from that with simple arithmetic.
- `if (seconds === 0)` is not a good condition to see if the timer has already started. Remember that the number of seconds is regularly set back to 0 (every time a minute passes). Instead, test whether the `intervalId` has been set, and clear it whenever you clear the timer.
- The number of seconds are traditionally displayed with 2 digits, so you should prefix with an extra "0" when the number of seconds is less than 10.

Here is how it could work. I removed all Cube related stuff, and CSS, as it is not related to your question:

```js
document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = "00";
document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = 0;

let intervalId;
let seconds = 0;

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    // -1 is used as a value to indicate that the timer was stopped
    if (event.key !== ' ' || intervalId === -1) return;
    if (intervalId !== undefined) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        intervalId = -1; // Don't allow time to restart
    } else {
        intervalId = setInterval(function() {
            seconds++;
            const secondsOnly = seconds % 60;
            const minutes = (seconds - secondsOnly) / 60;
            document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = ("" + secondsOnly).padStart(2, "0");
            document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = minutes;
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

```html
<span id="minutes"></span>:<span id="seconds"></span>
<p>Press the spacebar to start/stop the timer!</p>
```

Note that using `setInterval` is not a guarantee for having a precise time measurement. See [How to create an accurate timer in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29971898/5459839) for what you need to do to get a more accurate timing.

Comment: Thank you! can you also make it so that once the timer has been paused, it cannot be started again?

Comment: Sure, that is possible. Are you saying you don't know how to do that? Anyway, I updated the code to only allow one start and one stop.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a flow control statement like this:

```
if (seconds > 59 || seconds > 60 && seconds > 119 || seconds > 120 && seconds > 179 || seconds > 180 && seconds > 239) {...
```

doesn't work the way you'd expect it. Once `seconds` is 60 or more, the first condition will always returns `true` for every second that passes after the 59<sup>th</sup> second. There are many other syntactical errors and code smells that keep it from functioning, so instead of going through each one, we'll focus on a working solution instead. The following example has details commented within.

```js
// Reference <time>
const timer = document.getElementById("timer");
// Reference <form>
const main = document.forms.main;
// Reference <fieldset> and all <input>
const fc = main.elements;

/**
 * Variables declared within a function will be destroyed when
 * the function ends. So declare any variables that needs to 
 * maintain their value outside of any function.
 * Define "tick" outside of any function because it needs to
 * be accessed by multiple functions.
 */
let time = 0;
let seconds = 0;
let tick = null;

/**
 * This function is called every 1000ms (1sec) by "tick"'s setInterval().
 */
const clock = () => {
  // Declare "minutes" and "mmss", define "sec" as "seconds"
  let minutes, mmss, sec = seconds;
  // Increment "second" by 1.
  seconds++;
  // "minutes" is 1 for every 60 "seconds"
  minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
  /* When more than a minute has passed, "sec" is the remaining seconds 
     (less than 60) */
  if (minutes > 0) {
    sec = Math.floor(seconds % 60);
  }
  // This string is assigned to an element to display.
  mmss = `${String(minutes).padStart(2, "0")}:${String(sec).padStart(2, "0")}`;
  timer.datetime = mmss;
  timer.textContent = timer.datetime;
};

const start = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  fc.set.disabled = true;
  time = Number(fc.set.value);
  /* Redefine "tick" with setInterval() 
     call the clock() function
     set a condition when the predetermined time is reached */
  tick = setInterval(() => {
    clock();
    if (seconds >= time + 1) {
      clearInterval(tick);
      if (seconds === 3601) {
        timer.textContent = "1 HOUR";
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
};

const clear = e => {
  clearInterval(tick);
  fc.set.disabled = false;
  time = 0;
  seconds = 0;
  timer.datetime = "00:00";
  timer.textContent = "00:00";
};

const stop = e => clearInterval(tick);

main.onsubmit = start;
main.onreset = clear;
fc.stop.onclick = stop;
```

```css
:root {
  font: 2ch/1.15 "Segoe UI"
}

fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

legend {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

input {
  height: 2rem;
  font: inherit
}

[name="button"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ui {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 0.75rem;
}

#set,
#timer {
  font-family: Consolas
}

#set {
  width: 3.5rem;
  height: 1.8rem;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

#timer {
  display: block;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<form id="main">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Hour Timer</legend>
    <label for="set">Set number of seconds (max 3600)</label>
    <label class="ui">
      <input id="set" type="number" min="1" max="3600" value="1" required>
      <input name="button" type="submit" value="Start">
      <input id="stop" name="button" type="button" value="Stop">
      <input name="button" type="reset" value="Clear"></label>
    <time id="timer" datetime="00:00">00:00</time>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Checkout this simple script that I wrote:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    function countdownTimer(seconds) {
        const now = Date.now();
        const then = now + seconds * 1000;
    
        displayTime(then);
    
        // Update the countdown timer every second
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            const now = Date.now();
            const remainingSeconds = Math.round((then - now) / 1000);
    
            // If the countdown is finished, stop the interval and display a message
            if (remainingSeconds < 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            } else {
                displayTime(then);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
    
    // Function to display the remaining time
    function displayTime(timestamp) {

        const remainingSeconds = Math.round((timestamp - Date.now()) / 1000);
        if (remainingSeconds >= 0) {
            const minutes = Math.floor(remainingSeconds / 60);
            const seconds = remainingSeconds % 60;
            let displayTime = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
            $('.meh-count-down').text(displayTime);
        }
    }
    $('.countTimer').click(function(){
        countdownTimer(120);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
        <button class="countTimer">Press to start timer</button>
        <span class="meh-count-down"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do not post your code as an external link only; questions and answers need to be self-contained on Stackoverflow, in case the link expires or otherwise becomes inaccessible in the future. Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77539551/edit) and include your code as a code snippet.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, please accept my apologies